# I managed to fix the errors (LNK1169 and LNK2005) but why does this work?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

I managed to fix the error two different ways but I honestly don't know why it works. Can someone here please provide some clarification?

As is, the following code gives me the following errors

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall Person::Person(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0Person@@QAE@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in Person_Functions.obj        
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Program:

```
//**************
//Person_Class.h
//**************

#ifndef PERSON_CLASS_H
#define PERSON_CLASS_H

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct Person {
    string name;
    string address;

    string getName() const { return name; }
    string getAddress() const { return address; }

    Person() = default;
    Person(string n, string a) : name(n), address(a) {}
    Person(istream& is);
};

ostream& print(ostream&, const Person&);
istream& read(istream&, Person&);
Person::Person(istream& is) { read(is, *this); }

#endif

//********************
//Person_Functions.cpp
//********************

#include "Person_Class.h"

istream& read(istream& is, Person& p) {
    is >> p.name >> p.address;

    return is;
}

ostream& print(ostream& os, const Person& p) {
    os << p.getName() << " " << p.getAddress();

    return os;
}
```

If I write the header like this instead, the errors go away

```
//**************
//Person_Class.h
//**************

#ifndef PERSON_CLASS_H
#define PERSON_CLASS_H

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//This seems like a "duct tape" fix, feels messy and unorganized.  
struct Person;
istream& read(istream&, Person&);


struct Person {
    string name;
    string address;

    string getName() const { return name; }
    string getAddress() const { return address; }

    Person() = default;
    Person(string n, string a) : name(n), address(a) {}
    Person(istream& is) { read(is, *this); } 

//Defining istream constructor in the class definition fixes the issue 
//but as you can see above, this forces me to declare read above the struct
//which means I have to then declare the struct above read

};

ostream& print(ostream&, const Person&);

#endif

//This uses the same Person_Functions.cpp as before
```

The other solution I found is to instead define the istream constructor inside Person_Functions.cpp

I am really confused about why the first version doesn't work. Is there a preferred way to handle this and can someone provide some clarification here on the differences?

Sorry for the long post. I wasn't sure how much detail to include. Thanks for taking the time to teach me!

Comment: Use `inline Person::Person(istream& is) { read(is, *this); }` if you define it in the header instead of the implementation file to avoid the multiple definition error.

Comment: ***Is there a preferred way to handle this***  This part is an opinionated question however here goes: I usually put the definitions in the implementation file and keep them out of the header. If they are in the header I usually put them inside the class definition.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. I'll just stick to putting it in the implementation. Now that I think about it, I'm not sure why I didn't do that in the first place.